# Creating ROS Workspace - catkin_make catkin_pkg error

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS VERSION : INDIGO (desktop-full)
OS : Ubuntu 14.04

I install ROS using prebuild debian(sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full).
Going through ROS tutorials, i get the following error while creating a workspace(catkin_make)

```
ImportError: "from catkin_pkg.package import parse_package" failed: No module named catkin_pkg.package
Make sure that you have installed "catkin_pkg", it is up to date and on the PYTHONPATH.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/kyo/anaconda/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/kyo/catkin_ws/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:141 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

extra info : i had anaconda installed in my ubuntu and running echo $PYHTONPATH return nothing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172286/creating-ros-workspace---catkin_make-catkin_pkg-error/) by [kyo_udon](https://answers.ros.org/users/18741/kyo_udon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2014-05-31**:
`anaconda` may be interfering, can you do `python -c "import catkin_pkg; print(catkin_pkg.__version__)"`?

**Comment by [kyo_udon](https://answers.ros.org/users/18741/kyo_udon/) on 2014-05-31**:
This is what i got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ImportError: No module named catkin_pkg

**Comment by [Kailegh](https://answers.ros.org/users/21460/kailegh/) on 2017-03-13**:
i am having the same issue, got any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe that the issue is with a path conflict with ROS and Anaconda. I experienced the same thing a while back.

---

Originally posted by [candidcypher](https://answers.ros.org/users/20435/candidcypher/) with karma: 16 on 2015-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

$pip install catkin_pkg
solve the problem
Ubuntu 14.04
I got same erro when building ORK

---

Originally posted by [schwarmcyc](https://answers.ros.org/users/26007/schwarmcyc/) with karma: 36 on 2016-02-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tengfei](https://answers.ros.org/users/31490/tengfei/) on 2017-10-25**:
I have met the same problem and tried your method, then it works! Can you give me an detailed explanation what this command works?